# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: system.reactive

I get this warning but cannot find an explicit reference to the mentioned assembly.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b331ac6720247d9' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Google tells me this is something to do with the [Reactive Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29) and [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812160601/http://geekswithblogs.net/bdiaz/archive/2010/03/13/using-the-reactive-extensions-with-the-silverlight-toolkit-and-mef.aspx) suggests the problem has to do with early versions of the Silverlight Toolkit bundling 1.0.0.0

Does anyone know how to get rid of this warning? Perhaps I should remove the Silverlight Toolkit, then install the current version? Or possibly I should get the toolkit source and make the reference less version specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest Silverlight Toolkit then install the Reactive Extensions for Silverlight

Comment: Bizarre. An easy fix, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a half a day trying to resolve this problem.  If you have this problem and have git you can try the following solution that worked for me :

1. `git checkout -b [name for your recovery branch]`
2. backup the project folder
3. clone your project again `git clone [project clone url]`
4. `git checkout [name for your recovery branch]`

Luckily the problem seemed to be in the Git ignored Visual Studio files.

If this solution doesn't work for you, you can just restore your backed up project folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an old issue, but I have it at the moment with Vs2022 Dotnet Core 3.1.

To solve it, I simply closed the project and deleted the bin and obj folders. Then I reopened the project and rebuild. The problem is solved.

May be helpful for someone else.